# Replace characters in file line by line in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to replace some invalid characters that have been included in tsv text files I am processing. I need to replace the characters in the file. Because the files can be quite large I am trying to process them line by line.

What I have now is overwriting my files and leaving them blank. I know I am doing some things wrong with this, I'm just not sure about what I should be doing differently. Thanks for any advice.

```
  begin
   Dir["#{@data_path}*.tsv"].each do |dir_file|
       begin 
          File.open(dir_file, "w+") do |file|
            file.lines.each do |line|
             line.gsub(/\\t/, " ") 
             line.gsub(/\\/, " ")                  
             line.gsub(/\(\"/, "(") 
             line.gsub(/\"\)/, ")")
            end 
          end   
       rescue Exception => e
          @log.warn("Unable to replace the bad characters because #{e.message}")
          next
       end
    end      
  rescue
    nil
  end
```

Comment: You're missing sample data needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do the logic like this. It's untested because I don't have any sample data to work with, but it should be pretty close:

```
Dir["#{ @data_path }*.tsv"].each do |tsv_file|
  begin 
    File.open(tsv_file + '.new', 'w') do |file_out|
      File.foreach(tsv_file) do |line_in|
        file_out.puts line_in.gsub(/[\t\\]/, ' ').gsub('("', '(').gsub('")', ')')
      end   
    end
    File.rename(tsv_file, tsv_file + '.old')
    File.rename(tsv_file + '.new', tsv_file)
  rescue Exception => e
    @log.warn("Unable to replace the bad characters because #{ e.message }")
  end
end
```

Notice that I'm using `/[\t\\]/` to process both tabs and backslashes at once. And, it's not necessary to succumb to the "leaning-toothpick syndrome" caused by using double-quotes around your strings. Single-quotes are useful for cleaning them up.

You can't read and write to the same text file so `File.open(dir_file, "w+")` is not going to work. You have to read, process a line, then write to a new file, then, when you've reached the bottom of the input file, swap the new for the old file.

It's important to also keep the old file as long as possible before renaming and optionally deleting it. That way, if the code or host dies during processing the original file is intact and only the new file is affected.